# ASP.NET core, change default redirect for unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to redirect to a different login url in ASP.NET MVC6

My account controller login method has a `Route` attribute to change the url.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("login")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
    this.ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    return this.View();
}
```

> When attempting to access an unathorized page, I am redirected to the invalid url, it should just be `/login` but instead I get
>   **`http://localhost/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fhome%2Findex`**

I have configured the cookie authentication path as follows:

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
});
```

I have added a default filter, to ensure that all urls require authentication by default.

```
services.AddMvc(
    options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()));
    });
```

I have checked that the url `/login` does in fact load the login page, whilst `/account/login` does not, as expected.

**edit:** I have left the routes as is, (apart from changing the default controller and action)

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller=Site}/{action=Site}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Could you show your route config in `Configure()`?

Comment: @juunas:I have added the routes to the question

Comment: are you using asp.net-core-identity?

Comment: @tmg, yes I am, but with this plugin https://github.com/mrahhal/MR.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework6 to support EF6, I don't think the redirect will be affected by the EF version, but I could be wrong. I am still using `app.UseIdentity()` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you check `UseIdentity` extension method [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs) you will notice that it is using `IdentityOptions` not `CookieAuthenticationOptions`, so instead you must configure `IdentityOptions`:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
});
```

**Edit**

For asp.net core 2.0:
Identity cookie options are no longer part of IdentityOptions. Check mxmissile's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105434/asp-net-core-change-default-redirect-for-unauthorized/45922216#45922216).

Comment: I found it here too https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/539, thanks, works just fine.

Answer (score 72):

With `asp.net core 2.0` out now, this has changed to:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn");
```

More on [migrating to 2.0 here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x). And [even more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1#changes-to-authentication-code) on migrating from 2.0 to 2.1.

Update for latest Asp.NET 7.0, thanks @Chekkan:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Login");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for saving the day :D

Comment: `services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Login");`
With ASP.NET Core 7.0 the above worked for me.

Comment: doesn't work for me in asp.net core 7, with cookie options configured for login path "/login" I'm still getting redirected to "/Account/Login" when using `[Authorize]` attribute

Answer (score 19):

Since `asp.net core 2.0` if you use cookies without Identity:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

// If you don't want the cookie to be automatically authenticated and assigned HttpContext.User, 
// remove the CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme parameter passed to AddAuthentication.
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options => 
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOff";
    });
```

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x)

Comment: This is still valid for Core 3.0

Answer (score 12):

You may also want to try using `StatusCodePages`:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async contextAccessor => 
{
    var response = contextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;

    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized || 
        response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
        response.Redirect("/Error/Unauthorized");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to configure this in startup.cs when adding the authentication service especially if you're using cookie authentication scheme.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options => 
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
        });
```

This was how i solved the issue, you'll should try it out...It'll definitely work for you

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE:
As of dot net core 2.1.x, Identity is scaffolded from the SDK.
To co--sign @mxmissile answer, the path can be specified.  To pull off a trick path, combine with advanced routing or redirects.[Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-full-identity-ui-source)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend Serj Sagan solution in a real life example. This would work perfectly when developing but for a real application used by different types of user that might be misleading. Lets look at the below scenario

1. I am authenticated used
2. I know the url for a specific page
3. I am not authorize to access that pages

It means that I would be redirected to the login page as if I were not authenticated which is not the case. I would go more with mxmissile solution

Personnally I am using the AddMvcCore but you need to add AddRazorViewEngine if you are using razor views and AddRazorPages if you are using razor pages

```
        services.AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
        .AddRazorViewEngine()
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddJsonFormatters();
```

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the other referred answer).